# Codecept Laravel mock mysql database cast value to json

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, functional-testing, codeception

The mock I've created to fill the database with a row does not understand that it needs to cast the data into JSON before storing it to the database. For some reason, when the data from the mock is inserted into the database it skips casting to JSON. So when the logic then fetches the row from the database it returns this error.

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

If I have it as an array in the mock. It will produce this error when we decode in the controller.
If I encode it in the mock, it returns the same error.
If I encode it in the mock and remove the cast from the model, it works as expected.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

this is my mock

```
class SettingMocks
{
    public static function getSetting() {
        return [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Standard',
            'settings' => json_encode([
                'objective' => "CONVERSIONS",
                'gender' => [1,2],
            ])
        ];
    }
}
```

this is my model

```
class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $casts = [
        'settings' => 'json',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Read document carefully. You might need to use toJson() or it is for the serialized json . https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with [mutators and accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators) in your model like so:

```
public function getSettingsAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}

public function setSettingsAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['settings'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

Comment: this is what I tried. But the thing is, that the mock is not using the mutator, so it does not matter if I add one. The code in the controllers will. But not the mock.

Comment: Can you post the code from your mock that does that?